# Counting in a thread

Tags: java

Why would the program not print 9 instead of 0?
AtomicInteger did not help either (as advised)

```
 public class threadOne{
    //Integer i=0;
    AtomicInteger i=new AtomicInteger(0);

    class firstThread implements Runnable{
        AtomicInteger i;
        firstThread(AtomicInteger i){
            this.i=i;
        }
        public void run(){
            while(i.intValue()<10){
                i.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }       
    }

    void runThread(){ 
        Thread t = new Thread(new firstThread(i));
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Result : " + i.intValue());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new threadOne().runThread();

    }

}
```

Comment: Read my answer. And don't accept answer unless problem is solved. That gives an impression that problem is solved and everyone moves on.

Comment: Updated my answer. see

Comment: You should stick to the Java Naming Convention. Always start class names with an uppercase letter. Also, `threadOne` should extend `Thread`, because the name implies that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remember** : You're printing `i` of `threadOne`, and not `firstThread`

The `Integer i` in both the clases are *independent of each other*. Changes in one don't reflect on the other one. `Integer` is a immutable class.

For example,

```
Integer i = 4;
Integer j = i;
j = 1; //same as j = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(i);
```

It prints `4` and not `1`. The same way, `i+=1` in `firstThread` does not affect the `i` in `threadOne`, which is the one you're printing.

You can use a mutable class, like [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which does what you expect, or simply print `i` of `firstThread`

**Edit**: You need to wait for the execution of the Thread to complete to see the changes. Do

```
Thread t = new Thread(new firstThread(i));
t.start();
try{
    t.join();
}catch(Exception e){}
System.out.println("Result : " + i.get());
```

Comment: There is absolutely no relation of this question to using an **AtomicInteger**. That is for concurrent access. This is just scoping confusion.

Comment: @pulp_fiction The reason I mentioned `AtomicInteger` was because it can  be mutated, that is, in this example, it would print `9`, like the OP suggested to do.

Answer (score 0):

Because the statement,

`System.out.println("Result : " + i);`

refers to the field `i` in the `threadOne` class and that's what you are printing instead of the incremented `i` in `firstThread` class. Insert this statement inside the `firstThread` class to get 9.

So do something like,

```
    public void run(){
        while(i<10){
            i+=1;
        }
        // INSERT HERE
        System.out.println("Result : " + i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declared two variables called `i`.

```
public class threadOne{
    Integer i=0; // <--- first one here
    class firstThread implements Runnable{
        Integer i; // <--- second one here
        firstThread(Integer i){
            this.i=i; // <--- here you are accessing the second one
        }
        public void run(){
            while(i<10){
                i+=1; // <--- here you are accessing the second one
            }
        }       
    }
    void runThread(){ 


        Thread t = new Thread(new firstThread(i)); // <--- here you are accessing the first one
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Result : " + i); // <--- here you are accessing the first one

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new threadOne().runThread();    
    }

}
```

Basically what happened is that you are printing out the first `i`, while what the thread is changing is the second `i`.

To fix this, simply print the second `i` by doing this:

```
firstThread first = new firstThread(i); // we need a firstThread variable because we need to access the second i later
Thread t = new Thread(first);
t.start();
System.out.println("Result : " + first.i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer class is Immutable. 
It means that you cannot pass the value from outside and change it inside the method without returning new value!